# Convergence in probability for a sequence of estimators

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, probability-limit-theorems

Suppose we have a sample of $n$ random variables $X_1, \ldots,X_n$ where each $X_i$ has a Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda$. Define $\theta=\exp\{-\lambda\}$ and
$$
\tilde{\theta}_n=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\mathbb{1}_{\{0\}}(X_i)
$$

Is there a limit distribution for $\tilde{\theta}_n$? Please any help will be appreciated.

Comment: So $\overline\theta_n$ is the fraction of times $X_i=0$ ?  Can you work out $E\overline\theta_n$?  Or tell what the distribution of 
 $ n\overline\theta_n$ is?

Comment: $1_{\{0\}}(X_i)$ is such that $E(\tilde{\theta}_n)=P(X_i=0)=\exp\{-\lambda\}$

Comment: So $\overline\theta_n$ is a sample average of something with expectation $\theta$.  Do you know of any other examples of limiting distributions of sample averages?

Comment: I can see it now!, I suppose I have to apply the CLT, right?

Answer (score 1):

As you have already mentioned, $\mathbb E[\mathbb 1_{\{0\}}(X)]=\exp\{-\lambda\}=\theta$. Thus, you only have to work out the variance $\mathbb V[\mathbb 1_{\{0\}}(X)]=\sigma^2$ and then you can use CLT to show that $\sqrt{n}(\tilde\theta_n-\theta)\overset{d}{\to} \mathcal N(0, \sigma^2)$.